# What's a good profiler for a CLI based multi-threaded PHP application?

Tags: php, multithreading, command-line-interface

I've written a batch processor that runs multiple threads (pcntl_fork) and I'm getting some weird results when child processes go defunct and don't seem to let go of their resources.

Is there a good code profiler, trace utility I can use to 'watch' the parent process and children to see what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only profiler I know of is [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/). You can process the results with [Webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) or KCachegrind.

It gives performance statistics about your written PHP code, so you should be able to figure out if the problems are due to your code or some PHP/OS bug.

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug can both do [profiling](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and [interactive debugging](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote). There are several clients available to connect to the debugging process.